# How to create a user friendly URL for IIS web app?

Tags: domain-name-system, iis

I have an IIS server installed on our local server, which also functions as DC, DNS and DHCP.

I have a web app on this server, which I can access using this URL: http://srv01/rms/ (srv01 being the server hostname and rms being the app name - inetpub/wwwroot/rms).

I want to be able to just type 'rms' into the browser and access the app.

I tried to add a CNAME record to my DNS server, but it didn't solve the issue. Clearly I'm missing something here.

- Alias name: rms
- Fully qualified domain name: rms.company.local
- Fully qualified domain name for target host: srv01/rms.

How do I redirect make 'http://srv01/rms' to appear as 'rms'? Thanks

Comment: 1) configure IIS and DNS to make `http://rms/` served by this server. 2) set up a reverse proxy to forward the traffic from `http://rms/` to `http://srv01/rms/`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing. Redirection cannot be used here.

Comment: Hello, thanks. What exactly do you mean by step1? Thanks.